# How to find all matches for every string in collection using Spring data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have got a collection of strings. I need to find in database all file names that contains this string. Like a full matching "LIKE(%KEYWORD%)";

Here is my method

```
  Page<FilePdf> getByFileNameContainingInAndExtension(Collection<String> fileNames, String extension, Pageable pageable);
```

But it gives me an exception

> Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property containing found for type String! Traversed path: FilePdf.fileName.

**UPDATE**
Here is my repository

```
 public interface FilePdfRepository extends JpaRepository<FilePdf, Long> {
    Page<FilePdf> getByFileNameContainingInAndExtension(Collection<String> fileNames, String extension, Pageable pageable);
}
```

And here is my entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dlfileentry")
public class FilePdf {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "uuid_")
    private String id;
    @Column(name = "fileentryid")
    private Integer fileEntryId;
    @Column(name = "groupid")
    private Integer groupId;
    @Column(name = "filename")
    private String fileName;
    @Column(name = "folderid")
    private Integer folderId;
    @Column(name = "extension")
    private String extension;
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the entity and the repository definitions?

Comment: @SergeyBrunov, check updates pls

Comment: What about [querying by example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example)?

Answer (score 1):

use **findBy** instead of **getBy**

using **in** keyword

```
 public interface FilePdfRepository extends JpaRepository<FilePdf, Long> {
        Page<FilePdf> findByFileNameInAndExtension(Collection<String> fileNames, String extension, Pageable pageable);
    }
```

see Docs : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.11.6.RELEASE/reference/html/

Comment: thanx for an answer but it findByFileNameInAndExtension doesn't find full matches with words.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem is that the `ContainingIn` keyword does not belong to the Spring Data JPA.

The `Containing` keyword does support only a single value, not a collection.

Consider updating the repository as follows:

```
public interface FilePdfRepository extends JpaRepository<FilePdf, Long> {
    Page<FilePdf> getByFileNameContainingAndExtension(String fileName, String extension, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query using querydsl, the JPAQuery can be formed in the following manner :

```
Predicate finalPredicate(StringPath sp, List<String> filterValues) {
        BooleanBuilder bb = new BooleanBuilder();
        String value;
        for (Iterator arg2 = filterValues.iterator(); arg2
                .hasNext(); bb = bb.or(sp.containsIgnoreCase(value.trim().toLowerCase()))) {
            value = (String) arg2.next();
        }
        return bb;
    }
```